# How can I call a function repeat when user press a button until user release that button

Tags: android

In android,

How can I repeat calls a function from the time user press a button until he/she release that button?

I have check clickListener and longclicklistener, but it does not seem like they do what I want.

Thank you.

Comment: Can I adjust the   getLongPressTimeout() in ViewConfiguration to make it checks for longPress event more frequent? and implement my own LongPress event listener more often?

Comment: And how can I implement the TouchListener so that the default click action still works as normal?

Comment: possible duplicate of [android repeat action on pressing and holding a button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511423/android-repeat-action-on-pressing-and-holding-a-button)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `OnTouchListener`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener
{

    private Button button;

    // ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // ...

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
        button.setOnTouchListener(this);

        // ...
    }

    // ...

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        /* get a reference to the button that is being touched */
        Button b = (Button) v;

        /* get the action of the touch event */
        int action = event.getAction();

        if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            /*
                A pressed gesture has started, the motion contains
                the initial starting location.
            */
        }
        else if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            /*
                A pressed gesture has finished, the motion contains
                the final release location as well as any intermediate
                points since the last down or move event.
            */
        }
        else if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
        {
            /*
                A change has happened during a press gesture (between
                ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP). The motion contains the
                most recent point, as well as any intermediate points
                since the last down or move event.
            */
        }
        else if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)
        {
            /*
                The current gesture has been aborted. You will not
                receive any more points in it. You should treat this
                as an up event, but not perform any action that you
                normally would.
            */
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right:
Click: The user pressed and released his finger.
Touch: The user's finger is still on the device.

Maybe you should try with onTouchListener?
I've never used it...

Answer (score 0):

use OnTouchListener for calling function until button release by user as:

```
private OnTouchListener otl_conn = (OnTouchListener) new TouchListenerConn();
private Button bv = null;
bv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xxxxbutton);
bv.setOnTouchListener(otl_conn);
 class  TouchListenerConn implements OnTouchListener  
    {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            //call function here
            break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            //DO SOMETHING
            xxxx....;
            break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```